# How do I vertically center text and icons in Bulma?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, bulma

I'm trying to center an icon and text using Bulma and flexbox in a vue.js project, I tried to follow the answer from this question ([How to vertically center elements in Bulma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897794/how-to-vertically-center-elements-in-bulma)). My icon vertically centers but the text elements seem to be off-center with a few pixels of white space under them. They are both on the same baseline but means they aren't in line with my icon (see image below).

[image: Text off centre with icon]

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, I've included my code below, I'd appreciate any help possible please

```
 <template>
   <div class="singleProjectContainer" :key="project.id">
     <ul class="columns is-flex projectPreview" style="border-bottom: 0.5px solid #c1c1c1;">
       <div class="column is-1 is-flex projectIcon">
         <li>
          <div v-if="project.projectType === 'Identity'"class="projectIcon" >
           <img src="../static/SVG/Identity-Circle.svg" alt="circle icon for branding & identity" />
         </div>
     </li>
   </div>
   <div class="projectTitle column is-4">
     <li> <h3>{{ project.Name }}</h3> </li>
     </div>
     <div class="projectSummary column is-7">
       <li> <p>{{ project.Summary }}</p> </li>
     </div>
   </ul>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProjectItem',
  props: ['project'],
 }
</script>

<style scoped>

.columns {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

.singleProjectContainer {
 height: 72x;
 margin: 0px;
 }

.columns.projectPreview {
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

.projectIcon {
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 height: 100%;
 }

.projectTitle {
 height: 100%;
}

.projectIcon img {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
}

.projectTitle h3 {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-family: 'Sporting Grotesque_Regular';
 color: black;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.is-vcentered` selector related only to `columns`:
https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#vertical-alignment

```
.columns.is-vcentered {
    align-items: center;
}
```

### Bulma >= 0.9.1

Since Bulma, 0.9.1 we can use [flexbox helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/flexbox-helpers/):

> Combined with `is-flex`, all of the Flexbox CSS properties are available as Bulma helpers:
>
> - flex-direction
> - flex-wrap
> - justify-content
> - align-content
> - align-items
> - align-self
> - flex-grow
> - flex-shrink

Example:

```html
<div class="is-align-items-center is-flex"></div>
```

**Snippet:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="box list-item is-flex is-align-items-center  ">
      <span class="icon has-text-danger">
        <i class="fas has-text-success fa-2x fa-adjust"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 60px;  line-height: 1;">Hello world</h2>
      <h3 style="margin-left: auto;">Right text</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="box list-item  is-flex is-align-content-center">
      <span class="icon has-text-danger">
        <i class="fas has-text-danger fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 20px;">Item 2</h2>
      <h3 style="margin-left: auto;">Right text</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
```

### Bulma < 0.9.1 (Old answer)

For lists - **No** "built-in" way (by helpers) to align icons and text (yet).
One solution - use core `is-flex` and **one** CSS custom style (For `align-items: center;`) .

**Snippet:**

```css
/* one custom class (not from bulma core) */
li.vcenter{
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item is-flex vcenter">
      <span class="icon has-text-danger">
        <i class="fas has-text-success fa-2x fa-adjust"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 60px;  line-height: 1;">Hello world</h2>
      <h3 style="margin-left: auto;">Right text</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item  is-flex vcenter">
      <span class="icon has-text-danger">
        <i class="fas has-text-danger fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
      </span>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 20px;">Item 2</h2>
      <h3 style="margin-left: auto;">Right text</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
```

Related: [How to center text vertically with a large font-awesome icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309928/how-to-center-text-vertically-with-a-large-font-awesome-icon)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!
I got everything vertically centered with the help of your snippet and explanation. The only issue I run into now is when I set a custom font for my text the baseline is different from the default font so the two text lines end up off-centre but I force fixed it by putting a margin-top on them.