# How to vertically center a media object in Bulma?

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

The [Bulma documentation on media objects](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/media-object/) gives this example:

[image: bulma media object]

```
<article class="media">
  <figure class="media-left">
    <p class="image is-64x64">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
    </p>
  </figure>
  <div class="media-content">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        <strong>John Smith</strong> <small>@johnsmith</small> <small>31m</small>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ornare magna eros, eu pellentesque tortor vestibulum ut. Maecenas non massa sem. Etiam finibus odio quis feugiat facilisis.
      </p>
    </div>
    <nav class="level is-mobile">
      <div class="level-left">
        <a class="level-item">
          <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-reply"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="level-item">
          <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-retweet"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="level-item">
          <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="media-right">
    <button class="delete"></button>
  </div>
</article>
```

How can I vertically center the image 128x128.png on the left side?

What I checked already:

- [Discussion in the Bulma issue queue on how to vertically center elements](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1401)
- [SO question about centering columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897794/how-to-vertically-center-elements-in-bulma)

Comment: The links you mentioned already has this comment: https://nimb.ws/gENtkv You need to make use of a custom class for your solution.

Comment: @m4n0 Thanks, but that is about columns, and I'm asking about the media object.  Also, Bulma has changed a lot in the past three years, so I'm wondering if a better way to do it has been added in the meantime.